# Is it possible to extend the behavior of Symfony2 form_row()?

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to add a class in the div container when there's an error in that field? For example adding class has-error to the class attribute of the div container

```
{% block field_row %}
    <div class="form_row has-error">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock field_row %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% block field_row %}
    <div class="form_row{% if form_errors(form) %} has-error{% endif %}">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock field_row %}
```

Comment: Care to explain the code, instead of just dumping a block of code into an answer?

Comment: shall i really explain a simple if statement? ... `{% if form_errors(form) %} has-error{% endif %}` ... if `form_errors()` returns something else than an empty string / null (aka the form-field has errors) twig will output the string " has-error" at this position. anything else unclear? i'll explain whatever might be unclear here but i thought that one-liner should be pretty much self-explaining.

Comment: Well, your answer was flagged as Low-Quality in the review queue, being that it's just a code dump. I was just giving you the opportunity to help future visitors.

Comment: ah okay got you - i guess in this case the answer should be enough for any future visitor to be able to get this working. happy coding :)

Comment: Cool! Btw this is the same with form_label right? To have "has-error" class in label when there's error on that field. Because for now I implement the template manually like
{% for errorItem in form.user.firstName.vars.errors %}
  <label class="control-label has-error" for="{{ form.user.firstName.vars.id }}">{{ errorItem.message }}</label>
{% endfor %}